# File import callback not supported on truffle migrate

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I have a truffle project with the following contract (elided) that I'm running with truffle migrate:

```
    1 pragma solidity >=0.6.0;
    2
    3 // implements the ERC721 standard
    4 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
    5 // keeps track of the number of tokens issued
    6 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
    7 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
> Compiling ./contracts/NFT.sol

> Compilation warnings encountered:

    Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
--> project:/contracts/Creation.sol


ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> project:/contracts/NFT.sol:6:1:
  |
6 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> project:/contracts/NFT.sol:8:1:
  |
8 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> project:/contracts/NFT.sol:9:1:
  |
9 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.4.0 (core: 5.4.0)
Node v14.15.5
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Even though my contract works I had the same error... I just changed:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
```

To a more explicit form:

```
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
```

and bypass those red squiggles.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the following commands

```
$ npm init
$ npm i -s @openzeppelin/contracts
```